# System.Uri.ToString behaviour change after VS2012 install

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

After installing VS2012 Premium on a dev machine a unit test failed, so the developer fixed the issue. When the changes were pushed to TeamCity the unit test failed. The project has not changed other than the solution file being upgraded to be compatible with VS2012. It still targets .net framework 4.0

I've isolated the problem to an issue with unicode characters being escaped when calling `Uri.ToString`. The following code replicates the behavior.

```
Imports NUnit.Framework

<TestFixture()>
Public Class UriTest

   <Test()>
    Public Sub UriToStringUrlDecodes()
       Dim uri = New Uri("http://www.example.org/test?helloworld=foo%B6bar")

       Assert.AreEqual("http://www.example.org/test?helloworld=foo¶bar", uri.ToString())
    End Sub

End Class
```

Running this in VS2010 on a machine that does not have VS2012 installed succeeds, running this in VS2010 on a machine with VS2012 installed fails. Both using the latest version of NCrunch and NUnit from NuGet.

[image: Machine without VS2012 Install]

[image: Machine with VS2012 Install]

The messages from the failed assert are

```
  Expected string length 46 but was 48. Strings differ at index 42.
  Expected: "http://www.example.org/test?helloworld=foo¶bar"
  But was:  "http://www.example.org/test?helloworld=foo%B6bar"
  -----------------------------------------------------^
```

The documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring%28v=vs.100%29) for both .NET 4 and .NET 4.5 shows that `ToString` should not encode this character, meaning that the old behavior should be the correct one.

```
A String instance that contains the unescaped canonical representation of the Uri instance. All characters are unescaped except #, ?, and %.
```

After installing VS2012, that unicode character is being escaped.

The file version of System.dll on the machine with VS2012 is 4.0.30319.17929

The file version of System.dll on the build server is 4.0.30319.236

Ignoring the merits of why we are using `uri.ToString()`, what we are testing and any potential work around. Can anyone explain why this behavior seems to have changed, or is this a bug?

Edit, here is the C# version

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SystemUriCSharp 
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UriTest
    {

        [Test]
        public void UriToStringDoesNotEscapeUnicodeCharacters()
        {
            var uri = new Uri(@"http://www.example.org/test?helloworld=foo%B6bar");

            Assert.AreEqual(@"http://www.example.org/test?helloworld=foo¶bar", uri.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

A bit of further investigation, if I target .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.5 the tests fail, if I switch it to .NET 3.5 then it succeeds.

Comment: I'm aware that logic dictates that I'm doing something wrong and there won't be a bug in .NET, but I just can't work out why this is occurring.

Comment: Presumably `bool check = @"http://www.example.org/test?helloworld=foo¶bar" == uri.ToString();` is false, right?

Comment: Seen as no one has pointed out the problem yet, I've submitted it as a bug on connect. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758479/system-uri-tostring-behaviour-change

Comment: I wouldn't say logic dictates there won't be a bug in .NET, they have issues as well, for example when installing VS2012 on a machine with VS2010 SP1 on it kills the SQL CE interface driver in Visual Studio. I would call that a bug, via installation yes, but a bug nevertheless. This is an interesting problem and I am in agreement with you currently regarding why it changed.

Comment: @ChrisDiver According to the response to your connect report, `foo%B6bar` isn't valid. Do you agree? If so, I think you can post that as an answer to your own question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change is related to problems with earlier .NET versions, which have now changed to become more compliant to the standards. `%B6` is UTF-16, but according to the standards UTF-8 should be used in the Uri, meaning that it should be `%C2%B6`. So as `%B6` is not UTF-8 it is now correctly ignored and not decoded.

More details from the [connect report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758479/system-uri-tostring-behaviour-change) quoted in verbatim below.

> .NET 4.5 has enhanced and more compatible application of RFC 3987
>   which supports IRI parsing rules for URI's. IRIs are International
>   Resource Identifiers. This allows for non-ASCII characters to be in a
>   URI/IRI string to be parsed.
>
> Prior to .NET 4.5, we had some inconsistent handling of IRIs. We had
>   an app.config entry with a default of false that you could turn on:
>
> which did some IRI handling/parsing. However, it had some problems. In
>   particular it allowed for incorrect percent encoding handling.
>   Percent-encoded items in a URI/IRI string are supposed to be
>   percent-encoded UTF-8 octets according to RFC 3987. They are not
>   interpreted as percent-encoded UTF-16. So, handling “%B6” is incorrect
>   according to UTF-8 and no decoding will occur. The correct UTF-8
>   encoding for ¶ is actually “%C2%B6”.
>
> If your string was this instead:
>
> ```
>         string strUri = @"http://www.example.com/test?helloworld=foo%C2%B6bar";
> ```
>
> Then it will get normalized in the ToString() method and the
>   percent-encoding decoded and removed.
>
> Can you provide more information about your application needs and the
>   use of ToString() method? Usually, we recommend the AbsoluteUri
>   property of the Uri object for most normalization needs.
>
> If this issue is blocking your application development and business
>   needs then please let us know via the "netfx45compat at Microsoft dot
>   com" email address.
>
> Thx,
>
> Networking Team

Answer (score 8):

There are some changes introduced in .NET Framework 4.5, which is installed along with VS2012, and which is also (to the best of my knowledge) a so called "in place upgrade". This means that it actually upgrades .NET Framework 4.

Furthermore, there are [breaking changes documented in System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx#core). One of them says *Unicode normalization form C (NFC) will no longer be performed on non-host portions of URIs*. I am not sure whether this is applicable to your case, but it could serve as a good starting point in your investigation of the error.

Comment: Interesting, it explains why it changed - it could be a side effect of one of those breaking changes, I was hoping to have gotten a response via connect by now but no luck.

Comment: Good spot, however it does state that "This only affects applications that target the .NET Framework 4.5."

Answer (score 0):

In that situation you can't do like that.
The main issue is the character "¶".

In .Net we got a problem on character ¶.
You can make a research on that.

Take the uri' parameters one by one.
Add them by one by and compare them.
May be you can use a method for "¶" character to create it or replace it.

For example;

```
Dim uri = New Uri("http://www.example.org/test?helloworld=foo%B6bar")

Assert.AreEqual("http://www.example.org/test?helloworld=foo¶bar", uri.Host+uri.AbsolutePath+"?"+uri.Query)
```

that'll work

uri.AbsolutePath: /test

url.Host: http://www.example.org

uri.Query: helloworld=foo¶bar

Comment: It worked before I installed VS2012, and should work according to the MSDN documentation. I'm not interesting in a work around - that is simple, I'm interested it why it no longer works.