# Uri.ToString behaves differently on Build Server

Tags: c#

I have a unit test which passes locally but fails on the build server.

Here's the test:

```
[Test]
public void Test_UriToStringInCI()
{
    Assert.That(new Uri("http://example.com:64625/rules?q=some%2Ffeature").ToString(), Is.EqualTo("http://example.com:64625/rules?q=some%2Ffeature"));
}
```

Here's the response I get back from the build server:

> Expected:
>   "http://example.com:64625/rules?q=some%2Ffeature"
>
> But was: 
>     "http://example.com:64625/rules?q=some/feature"

NOTE: the difference is on the build server the "/" in "some/feature" is being decoded, when locally it is not.

Why is my local machine behaving differently?

**EDIT - more info**

Looks like the CI server is behaving correctly. According to [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/278867/uri-tostring-returns-invalid-url-by-erroneously-urldecoding-each-argument) Uri.ToString() *should* escape all the characters, and Uri.OriginalString is the property I should be looking at.

So what is up with my local machine?

Comment: Sounds like you have exact same issue I had. The same topic is discussed [here on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004214/system-uri-tostring-behaviour-change-after-vs2012-install)

Comment: @Riz Thanks for the comment. Our problems are possibly related, but I'm confused. I'm targeting the same framework on the build server and locally, so why the difference? Also, %2F is valid escape for / in UTF-8, so there should be no problems there either.

Comment: I have checked and %2F gets translated to / for framework version 4 and below. But for 4.5 it doesn't. It looks really odd to have different results for same framework version. Btw, what version you have? On the other hand, Uri.ToString() doesn't escapes all characters (?, #, %)

Comment: I'm targeting framework 4.5. And that doesn't change from local to CI. I mean, it's the same csproj being compiled, so I can't explain the difference at all.